# Module.exports: is not a constructor error

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Can someone explain why the first export throws a `is not a constructor` error, while the second export works?

```
// Throws a `is not a constructor` error
module.exports = {
    Person: function () {
        constructor()
        {
            this.firstname;
            this.lastname;
        }
    }
}

// Works
class Person {
    constructor()
    {
       this.firstname = '';
       this.lastname = '';
    }
}
module.exports = Person;

// Usage:
const Person = require("person");
let person = new Person();
```

Comment: You're exporting an object with a field called 'Person'.  'new' needs to be called with a function or a class that has a constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the first time you actually export an object containing a property:

```
  module.exports = { /*...*/ };
```

And you can't construct that object. However you could get the Person property and construct that:

```
 const Person = require("person").Person;
 new Person();
```

You could also destructure the imported object:

```
 const { Person } = require("person");
 new Person();
```

... but that only makes sense if there are other things exported there otherwise I would go with v2.